# How to enable multisession in X11RDP?

Tags: x11rdp

I am using X11RDP v0.6. In the XRDP v0.5 multi-session was a choice by just changing the resolution. Anyway, this is not the problem...

I just want to know how to enable multi-session in X11RDP 0.6 in Ubuntu 12.04?

I already tried to mess up with the **sesman.ini** and **xrdp.ini** but it seems something in other place must be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[check this wiki](http://ubuntuwiki.net/index.php/Xrdp,_installing)

you need to add ports for each session in **/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini**

like this:

```
[globals]
bitmap_cache=yes
bitmap_compression=yes
port=3389
crypt_level=low
channel_code=1

# set empty username because VNC auth 
# doesn't actually use username, so no
# point in asking the user for one.

[xrdp1]
name=Active Local Login
lib=libvnc.so
username=
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=5900

[xrdp2]
name=Clean Session
lib=libvnc.so
username=
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=5901
```

and issue the following command for each session:

```
vncserver :1
```

Comment: I've checked your answer but there is something unclear for me.. Why should i use the command vncserver: 1

Comment: I can't explain everything in comments. let's chat

Comment: Ok but i dont have much time but i really wanna know your point of view

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12951/all-about-x11rdp join me here